# Deployment group not showing in Azure DevOps release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to follow these instructions:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-deploygroups

I get to step 6 under "Define your CD release pipeline" and get stuck. I have a Deployment group created and can see my Windows VM in the groups targets. DevOps says that the target is online. But when I'm in the pipeline editor and trying to select the deployment group for the IIS Deployment job, no deployment groups appear in the dropdown. When I type in the name of my deployment group it just says "Deployment Group does not exist". Does anyone know why my deployment group is not detected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We figured this out. The deployment group was created by someone else and I had only been granted Reader and not User permissions for the group.